# customKeyIdentifier value not working as x5t after uploading public certificate

Tags: azure, certificate, azure-active-directory, azure-authentication

I was trying to obtain JWT token from Microsoft Azure Active Directory using [Certificate credentials for application authentication.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-certificate-credentials) I am using **customKeyIdentifier** value as **x5t** while generating the JWT token)

There are two ways to create the app

```
1) App Registrations(Legacy)
2) App Registrations
```

[image]

After creating the app **test-app-13** from any of above two places.
I uploaded the same public certificate file from two paths below to get the
**customKeyIdentifier**.

**1) AzureActiveDirectory-> AppRegistrations(Legacy) -> test-app-13->Settings->Keys->Upload public key**

```
header = {
"alg": "RS256",
"typ": "JWT",
"x5t": "oO/ImH7U2wcypCvrY+iYalHOOmg="
};
```

When I am using **"x5t": "oO/ImH7U2wcypCvrY+iYalHOOmg="** then authentication works.

[image]

**2) AzureActiveDirectory-> AppRegistrations -> test-app-13-> Certificates & secrets -> Upload certificate**

```
header = {
"alg": "RS256",
"typ": "JWT",
"x5t": "A0EFC8987ED4DB0732A42BEB63E8986A51CE3A68"
};
```

But when I am using **"x5t": "A0EFC8987ED4DB0732A42BEB63E8986A51CE3A68"** then I keep getting error

```
  {  
  "error":"invalid_client",
  "error_description":"AADSTS700027: Client assertion contains an invalid 
  signature. [Reason - The key was not found., Thumbprint of key used by 
  client: 
  '0341050BCF7CEC40F80C1D3BDF6038D81101EB713CF7CE80E75084DC0EBC', Please 
  visit 'https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer' 
  and query for 
  'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/2e452b20-df6d-4228- 
  83c6-5742b1a8f59c' to see configured keys]\r\nTrace ID: 0a77a624- 
  684d-4145-9ce5-d19e1b6ccb00\r\nCorrelation ID: 09254eb4-6128-4e18-a 
  bf6-70b5e9a68960\r\nTimestamp: 2019-05-09 12:39:29Z",
  "error_codes":[700027],
  "timestamp":"2019-05-09 12:39:29Z",
  "trace_id":"0a77a624-684d-4145-9ce5-d19e1b6ccb00",
  "correlation_id":"09254eb4-6128-4e18-abf6-70b5e9a68960"
  }
```

[image]

.

My question is why "x5t": "A0EFC8987ED4DB0732A42BEB63E8986A51CE3A68I" not working if uploading the public certificate from path **AzureActiveDirectory-> AppRegistrations -> test-app-13->Settings-> Certificates & secrets -> Upload certificate**
and why the value of customKeyIdentifier is generated differently from these two places?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two values you reference are the same, [try running this hex2base64 on them.](http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php?lang=en)

One is base64 encoded `oO/ImH7U2wcypCvrY+iYalHOOmg=` and the other a hexadecimal representation `A0EFC8987ED4DB0732A42BEB63E8986A51CE3A68I`.

It appears that the graph service only supports the value when base64 encoded.

Comment: Hi, thanks for noting us to convert hex2base64, because it wasn't clear on microsoft apis => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-certificate-credentials